# Is there a way to fire the SOAP request from Selenium and get the response back to any file

Tags: selenium, soap

In the application which I am automating, below is the requirement.

1. Need to run the request in the SOAPUI.
2. This will generate the token response for the provided request.
3. We will need to use this token in constructing the URL for opening up the application. The token is driven by timestamp. So this will change for every trigger.

Please let me know if there is a way to fire the SOAP request from Selenium and get the response back or to any file.

Answer (score 0):

I simply used Java code for my Soap requests. For editing data in my XML I used the DOM parser. Here is the code I used for this:

```
    @When("^Soap call is made")
    public void soap_call_is_made() throws Exception {
    XMLHandling xml = new XMLHandling();
    String url = "URL here";

    String xmlPath = getClass().getResource("location/of/file.xml").getPath();
    Document document = xml.getXMLFile(xmlPath);
    SOAPMessage soapResponse =xml.makeSoapCall(document, url);

    // print SOAP Response
    System.out.print("Response SOAP Message:");
    soapResponse.writeTo(System.out);

}
```

The last line will get the token which is in the response.

Edit:
To get specific data from the response, use:

```
String tagName = "tagnameYouNeed"
String value = xml.getValueByTagName(soapResponse, tagName);
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. Could you please give more information on the XMLHandling class and the makeSoapCall() function.

Answer (score 0):

No, Selenium does not handle SOAP/REST request. Instead, you can use java or cURL to handle this situation. Alternatively you can also check [rest-assured](https://github.com/jayway/rest-assured) for this.